# Trying to Pull Over Data from a Different Sql Server in Microsoft SQL Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to pull over data from another SQL Server into a table on another server and I keep getting errors here is my query I have tried to change several things but I think it just is not seeing the other server from the openquery.  Here is my code?

```sql
USE ARLP_ARIES_DATA
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_AC_Property_master]
    
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[ARIES_AC_PROPERTY_PROVED]


    
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[ARIES_AC_PROPERTY_PROVED]
    (UWI,
    ARLP_EVAL,
    JCR_EVAL,
    LEASE,
    RSV_CAT,
    FIELD,
    HOLE_TYPE,
    RESERVOIR,
    OPERATOR,
    COUNTY,
    STATE,
    BASIN,
    API,
    PRODUCING_ENTITY_ID,
    FIRST_PROD,
    SPUD_DATE,
    COMPL_DATE,
    START_DATE,
    LAT_LEN,
    LL_MULT,
    SHLAT,
    SHLONG,
    BHLAT,
    BHLONG)

    
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(PRTDMINSQL1, AC_PROPERTY
    UWI,
    ARLP_EVAL,
    JCR_EVAL,
    LEASE,
    RSV_CAT,
    FIELD,
    HOLE_TYPE,
    RESERVOIR,
    OPERATOR,
    COUNTY,
    STATE,
    BASIN,
    API,
    PRODUCING_ENTITY_ID,
    FIRST_PROD,
    SPUD_DATE,
    COMPL_DATE,
    START_DATE,
    LAT_LEN,
    LL_MULT,
    SHLAT,
    SHLONG,
    BHLAT,
    BHLONG)
;
END
```

I keep getting this error, if I change it to `[dbo].[AC_PROPERTY]`?

> Incorrect syntax near 'AC_PROPERTY'

I still get this Incorrect syntax near 'dbo'  any suggestions please

Comment: The second parameter of `OPENQUERY` requires a literal string, which is a query; as shown in the documentation's [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#a-executing-an-update-pass-through-query). You have 10's of column names as parameters? Have another read of the documentation on how `OPENQUERY` works and you'll see where you've gone wrong.

Comment: Ok I changed the query to use the Openquery example and now I am getting this Error: Could not find server 'PRTDMINSQL1' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.  Is their a way to make it see the PRTDMINSQL1 server?